# Which languages can be embedded into HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

As far as I know:

- **CSS** can be embedded via `<style>`
- **JavaScript** can be embedded via `<script>`
- **MathML** can be embedded via `<math>`
- **SVG** can be embedded via `<svg>`

Are there any other languages that can be embedded into HTML5?

If so, could you show me the examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s not really any restriction. For instance, you can embed whatever language you want into `<script>` tags or via CSS. The following is entirely valid:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/x-my-cool-language">
            PrintTheAnswer()
        </script>
        <script src="my-cool-interpreter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body> …
    </body>
</html>
```

Same for CSS. Some technologies *do* harness this, in particular things like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#usage). In both cases, the actual interpretation of the embedded language is handled by a JavaScript that is loaded additionally (just like in the above example).

Comment: but how to let web browsers execute the "x-my-cool-language"? E.g. `<script type="C++">`

Comment: @Sibi It doesn’t have to. No browser supports LESS or CoffeeScript to my knowledge. Support is added by loading a JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: @JackWM See update in the answer. But this is just one way of many. Theoretically, you could add support for these languages in the browser directly. Google planned that for Chrome and their JavaScript “killer”, Dart. No idea whether support has already been added though. Another way of adding support is via a plugin in the browser.

Comment: the languages under `<script>` should be programming language, right? e.g. PHP. Then how about non-programming ones, e.g. XML

Comment: [JavaScript templating liberaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates) also use similar features very heavily - they load a JavaScript script that knows how to handle custom scripts, or even expand the HTML and add inline templates.

Comment: @JackWM The language in `script` tags can be whatever you like. There’s also no clear-cut separation between programming languages and other languages. For instance, XSLT is XML but it’s also a full-blown programming language. Same for ColdFusion.